# Using a MySQL database on Windows Phone 7?

Tags: mysql, windows-phone-7

I'm attempting to write a Windows Phone 7 application which needs to connect to a remote data source, in this case it's a MySQL database on a Linux server.  I'm not able to move this over to MSSQL, nor to build any kind of windows-based solution (like a WCF web service on the server).

Is there a way for me to use my MySQL database from my Windows Phone 7 application?  The MySQL assemblies don't seem to work on the phone.  If not, what would the best solution for me to use this database from the phone?

Comment: am also trying same thing in my app(am new to wp7), can u please guide me to achieve this, have u write any services ?? please help me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could build your self a service which would send you json or xml. this can easily be built using mono, python, Ruby, php or any technology that you are comfortable with.

You can build it in a restful manner where all you have to do is call urls in a HTTP GET to retreive data which you handle with the services.

and use the HTTP POST to submit changes to your service.

you can then from WP7 make calls to this service and consume the data.

WP7 does not support sockets at the moment. So your best bet is transfering your payloads over HTTP.

As I mentioned before, if you have access to the machines configuration. You could run Mono which isn't too far off of .Net in terms of language and functionality.

further more, from the phone you can use the Rx library to make these calls Async and keep your application responsive.