# Windows Phone 7 and MySql.Data.CF

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, mysql-connector

Can't add the MySql.Data.CF assembly to a Windows Phone project

[image: Error]

Have tried MySQL Connector/Net 6.8.3 as well. How can I fix this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using a MySQL database on Windows Phone 7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5277773/using-a-mysql-database-on-windows-phone-7)

Comment: No mention of MySQL Connector/Net in that question

Comment: Eh, marked to close as dupe of the wrong one.  Anyhow, you fix it by using a connector that was built for the runtime.  If you're asking for a link to such a connector, that's off topic for a different reason.